# Query not inserting data

Tags: php, mysql

trying to submit data from a form but does not seem to be working. Can't spot any problems?

```
        //Include connect file to make a connection to test_cars database
        include("prototypeconnect.php");

        $proId              =       $_POST["id"];
        $proCode            =       $_POST["code"];
        $proDescr           =       $_POST["descr"];
        $proManu            =       $_POST["manu"];
        $proCPU             =       $_POST["cpu"];
        $proWPU             =       $_POST["wpu"];
        $proBarCode         =       $_POST["barcode"];
        $proIngredients     =       $_POST["ingredients"];
        $proAllergens       =       $_POST["allergenscon"];
        $proMayAllergens    =       $_POST["allergensmay"];

        //Insert users data in database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO prototype.Simplex_List (id, code, descr, manu, cpu, wpu, barcode, ingredients, allergenscon, allergensmay) 
        VALUES ('$proId' , '$proCode', '$proDescr' , '$proManu' , '$proCPU' , '$proWPU' , '$proBarCode' , '$proIngredients' , '$proAllergens' , '$proMayAllergens')";

        //Run the insert query
        mysql_query($sql)
```

Comment: What happens when you try? Do you get an error message, or does it just not load?

Comment: any errors or something else?

Comment: Do you need to do a commit on the database transaction?

Comment: Insert query looks good. Try to capture some errors.

Comment: You must have mispelled a table column, or might have an empty field. Try looking in your apache error logs.

Comment: Before you get values from POST, please use if(isset($_POST)). It is a good practise. Don't use mysql. Use either mysqli or PDO. echo every post values to test.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stuck at this error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column '\_\_\_\_' at row 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31699244/stuck-at-this-error-incorrect-integer-value-for-column-at-row-1)

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, please do not use `mysql_***` functions and please use prepared statements with 
`PDO` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
or `mysqli` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php instead. Prepared statements *help* protect you against sql injection attempts by disconnecting the user submitted data from the query to the database.

You may want to try using `mysql_real_escape_string` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php to ensure no stray `"` or `'` is breaking your query.

```
    $proId              =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);
    $proCode            =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["code"]);
    $proDescr           =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["descr"]);
    $proManu            =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["manu"]);
    $proCPU             =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["cpu"]);
    $proWPU             =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["wpu"]);
    $proBarCode         =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["barcode"]);
    $proIngredients     =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ingredients"]);
    $proAllergens       =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["allergenscon"]);
    $proMayAllergens    =       mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["allergensmay"]);
```

Additionally ensure your form is being submitted by calling `var_dump($_POST)` to validate the data

You can also see if the query is erroring by using `mysql_error` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

```
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
   echo mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

advices about PDO, prepared statements were done.

**1)** Do you have a database and connection to it?
Look at your prototypeconnect.php and find database name there. check that its name and password is similar that u have.

**2)** Do you have a table named `prototype.Simplex_List` in your database?

**a)** IF YOU HAVE: 
check if your mysql version  >= 5.1.6 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

**b)** IF YOU HAVE BUT ITS NAME is `Simplex_List`:

**b-1)** if your database name IS NOT `prototype`:

replace your

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO prototype.Simplex_List
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Simplex_List
```

**b-2)** if your database name IS `prototype`:

you should escape your $_POST data with `mysql_real_escape_string` as @fyrye said.

**c)** IF YOU HAVE NOT:
you should create it

**3)** Check your table structure

does it have all theese fields `id, code, descr, manu, cpu, wpu, barcode, ingredients, allergenscon, allergensmay`?

if you have there PRIMARY or UNIQUE keys you should be sure you are not inserting duplicate data on them

but anyway replace your

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO
```

PS: its not possible to help you without any error messages from your side