# Stuck at this error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column '____' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

When I submit the form and use this script to insert the data in the db i get the error mentioned above...any ideas?

```
        //Include connect file to make a connection to test_cars database
        include("prototypeconnect.php");


        $proCode            =       $_POST["code"];
        $proDescr           =       $_POST["description"];
        $proManu            =       $_POST["manufacturer"];
        $proCPU             =       $_POST["cost_per_unit"];
        $proWPU             =       $_POST["weight_per_unit"];
        $proBarCode         =       $_POST["bar_code"];
        $proIngredients     =       $_POST["ingredients_list"];
        $proAllergens       =       $_POST["allergens_contains"];
        $proMayAllergens    =       $_POST["allergens_may_contain"];

        //Insert users data in database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO prodb.simplex_list 
                   code, description, manufacturer, 
                   cost_per_unit, weight_per_unit, bar_code,
                   ingredients_list, allergens_contains,
                   allergens_may_contain) 
                VALUES 
                  ( '$proCode', '$proDescr' , '$proManu', 
                   '$proCPU' , '$proWPU' , '$proBarCode', 
                   '$proIngredients' , '$proAllergens', 
                   '$proMayAllergens')";

        //Run the insert query

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo mysql_error();
        }

    ?>
```

UPDATE: I removed id inserts as they are auto-increment and i learned from your answers that a null does not need to be coded and mysql looks after AI. Thanks guys!

Comment: remove single quotes from $id in insert query. Also check if filed is type integer in db then not to pass single quotes.

Comment: @DishaV. actually my id is auto incrementing so i removed that...still same error

Comment: I find it helpful if you can echo the complete sql before attempting to insert /update etc if there are any problems. Then try that command directoy in your mySql client application (heidi etc) - just a thought

Comment: execute this statement on mysql server either directly or from any gui like sqlyog etc and check what error it produce.

Comment: This depends upon your MySQL table column definitions. There is at least one field which is defined as `INT` and you are inserting non-integer/string value there.

Comment: @CianWoods Can you share create table simplex_list query with data type?

Comment: Cian was your `id` field defined as `auto increment`? If so you normally leave those auto inrement fields out of the INSERT query as they are looked after by MySQL itself. **Changing the datatype just masks the issue it does not fix it** _Likely as not you will later have problems with using integer values that have been stored as text._

Comment: @CianWoods Just by changing the INT to Varchar won't be a right solution. Perhaps you have to use INT in some cases based on your programming logic. Please explain what were your fields used INT?

Comment: @kuttyraj i was using cost_per_unit and weight_per_unit as int

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes ID is auto-increment...have no idea how to fix it?

Comment: Just leave the `id` column off the column list and also remove the `'$proId' ,` from the parameter list. MySQL will take care of creating that column for you and ensuring its uniqueness. See @AK-Sonu answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, removed the id variables and such and just changed back types to int and it working now. Thank you!

Comment: Dont forget to mark @AK-Sonu answer as correct. I have edited out the mistake and formatted it so its a bit more readable

Comment: @RiggsFolly yep just marked it :) he says its bad to use mysql_* instead of mysql_* but is it ok to use mysql_error()? or should mysql_error() work?

Comment: As you are obviously just learning, I suggest you start by learning either the `mysqli_` or `PDO` database access extensions. The `mysql_` extensions are dead and have been removed completely from the soon to be released PHP7. Unfortunately most tutorials on the web use `mysql_` extensions, but you just have to ignore them completely from now on

Comment: Unfortunately `mysqli` and `pdo` are completely different. You cannot use anything out of the `mysql_*` set of instructions. They are completely different but now is the time to make the effort to learn these new extensions. Other wise you are wasting your time learning the `mysql_*` extension

Comment: _Never pass your parmeters in your SQL query without escaping them!_ It's a severe security issue, with that code you use anyone can run a query in your database through the form.

Comment: [This post is a VERY GOOD READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) and shoud help you make your mind up to move and what to move to.

Comment: @vard can you point out where I'm doing this?

Comment: @CianWoods When you do this  `$proCode  = $_POST["code"];` then this `VALUES ('$proCode'` you pass your POST parameter directly into the query without escaping it. If I put something like this  `);DROP TABLE prodb.simplex_list` in a form field it will delete your table. You can escape the POST datas by using [`mysqli_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php).

Comment: @vard ah wow! I should ALWAYS use mysqli_escape_string so when using POST from forms..

Comment: @CianWoods Personally I like to use [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), that way parameters are always escaped, so I don't have to worry about them. And when you're passing an integer, you can parse it as int in that way: `$my_integer = (int) $my_integer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query need to be like:-

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO prodb.simplex_list 
         (code, description, manufacturer, 
          cost_per_unit, weight_per_unit, 
          bar_code, ingredients_list, allergens_contains, 
          allergens_may_contain) 
         VALUES ('$proCode', '$proDescr', '$proManu',
                 '$proCPU','$proWPU', '$proBarCode', 
                 '$proIngredients', '$proAllergens', 
                 '$proMayAllergens')";
```

**Note:- please stop using `mysql_*`. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Also this will work only when `id` field must be auto incremented.**

Comment: Hi, please remove id from insert. as you dont pass the prodid.

Comment: Hi, No need to use id. Remove that field. As well as remove empty ' ' parameter inside VALUES(). Like this,        $sql = "INSERT INTO prodb.simplex_list (code, description, manufacturer, cost_per_unit, weight_per_unit, bar_code, ingredients_list, allergens_contains, allergens_may_contain) 
        VALUES ('".$proId."' , '".$proCode."', '".$proDescr."' , '".$proManu."' , '".$proCPU."' ,'".$proWPU."' , '".$proBarCode."' , '".$proIngredients."', '".$proAllergens."', '".$proMayAllergens."')";

Comment: @AK-Sonu why should i stop using mysql_* instead of mysqli? causes more errors saying I'm missing parameters...

Comment: because now `mysql_*` is deprecated library officially.

Comment: Hope you dont mind I edited the `'$proId' ,` out of the parameter list and removed all the unnecessary concatenation, and formatted it so it can be read easily

Comment: No you have to stop use any function related to `mysql_*`.

Comment: @AK-Sonu it expects one parameter, what parameter do i pass it?

Comment: check it on `php.net` site. you will get complete reference for it. check this link:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php